# Show URL in the title of LWC lightning-map

Tags: lightning-web-components, map, salesforcedx-cli, lightning-map

**The image from my Lightning web component**
[image: The image from my Lightning web component]

**That's what I want to achieve**
[image: That's what I want to achieve]
I am implementing lightning-map for one of my clients.
I actually need to show the URL or a button that would open google map in a new tab.
Please advise me how can I achieve this requirement.
Below is my LWC code.

**HTML Page**

```
<template>
  <lightning-map
      map-markers={mapMarkers}
      markers-title={markersTitle}
      center={center}
      list-view='visible'
      onmarkerselect={handleMarkerSelect}
      selected-marker-value={selectedMarkerValue}
      show-footer
  >
  </lightning-map>
</template>
```

**JS Controller**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class LightningMapExample extends LightningElement {
    mapMarkers = [
        {
            location: {
                Street: '1000 5th Ave',
                City: 'New York',
                State: 'NY',
            },
            
            title: 'Metropolitan Museum of Art',
            description: 'A grand setting for one of the greatest collections of art, from ancient to contemporary.',
            value: 'SF1'
            
        },
        {
            location: {
                Street: '1000 5th Ave',
                City: 'New York',
                State: 'NY',
            },
            value: 'SF2',
            type: 'Circle',
            radius: 200,
            strokeColor: '#FFF000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FFF000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            
        },
        {
            location: {
                Street: '11 W 53rd St',
                City: 'New York',
                State: 'NY',
            },
            value: 'SF3',
            title: 'Museum of Modern Art (MoMA)',
            description: 'Thought-provoking modern and contemporary art.',
            
        },
        {
            location: {
                Street: '1071 5th Ave',
                City: 'New York',
                State: 'NY',
            },

            title: 'Guggenheim Museum',
            description:
                'World-renowned collection of modern and contemporary art.',
        },
    ];

    markersTitle = 'Coordinates for Centering';
    selectedMarkerValue = 'SF3';
    center = {
        location: { Latitude: '40.7831856', Longitude: '-73.9675653' },
    };

    handleMarkerSelect(event) {
        this.selectedMarkerValue = event.target.selectedMarkerValue;
    }
}
```